# Что происходит с виртуальными адресами после вызова fork()?

Tags: linux, память, x86-64, виртуальная-память, fork

После вызова **fork** мы "копируем" все данные у процесса, в котором мы вызывали fork(используя механизм **COW**), так же при смене контекста мы заменяем регистр **CR3**(x86_64) и загружаем новые таблицы страниц.
Если рассмотреть какую-то переменную из процесса родителя, то в дочернем процессе мы получим **другое значение виртуального адресса этой переменной, но она будет "ссылаться" на одну и ту же область в физической памяти** и это значение (в физической памяти) поменяется только и только если мы захотим изменить значение этой переменной, в дочернем процессе.

**1)** Правильно ли я понял описанное выше?
**2)** Для чего нужен регистр CR3?

Comment: Правильнее сказать -- "в дочернем процессе мы **можем получить** другое значение виртуального адресса этой переменной, ...".  По крайней мере в небольших (демо) программах *численные значения* виртуальных адресов будут совпадать. При изменении переменной в дочернем процессе изменится ее *физический адрес*. Что касается регистра [CR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register), то он содержит адрес начала дерева таблиц трансляции виртуальных адресов процесса в физические